# Array result from INDIRECT

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So, I have a Google Sheet connected to a Google Form that I use for debugging a series of games. Each game has a Unit number and an Activity number.

I added to the sheet a column that, basing on the Unit and on the Activity, retrieves the name of the developer, contained in another sheet.

```
=INDIRECT("Developers!"&CHAR(C1+64+1)&(B1+1))
```

(I have to add 1 to each value because the other table has headers)

The formula does work on a single cell, but it's not applied to the new lines inserted by the Google Form.

I've seen that ARRAYFORMULA() returns an array that automatically populates the cells below.

Is there a command I can use to apply a formula to an array of values and have an array of results returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get just a range do:

```
=INDIRECT("Developers!"&ADDRESS(B1+1, C1+1, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), C1+1, 4))
```

or populated range:

```
=INDIRECT("Developers!"&ADDRESS(B1+1, C1+1, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(B:B), C1+1, 4))
```